# Exponential Distribution Alarm System

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to create an alarm system where I'm able to detect when a metric is behaving abnormally.

The metric is a financial one, say EPX, Earning per Unit, which means that each unit earns money over time, and is not earnings from sale of the units. I plotted the distribution and have noted that the distribution is Exponential.

I'm mostly interested in knowing when the metric is lower than some threshold over a sustained period of time, say lower than the mean or lower than some quantile for x consecutive minutes. However, considering that the metric is distributed exponentially, most of the entries are very low and thus would generate a lot of false positives.

I'm having trouble thinking of the best way to approach this problem and would appreciate some input.
Below is a histogram in percentage of Earning per Unit per minute, EPX, as requested.

---

[image]

Comment: You appear to contradict yourself: if indeed the metric is "lower than a threshold for a sustained period of time," then there can be no such thing as a "false positive": it either was lower or it wasn't.  Could you be more precise about the purpose of this "alarm system"?

Comment: Sure. Apologies for the confusion. If I were to take samples of new data every minute and compare it to a fitted exponential distribution, how can I know if the samples are abnormally low for a sustained period of time. It's okay if each sample is below some threshold for 1 or 2 minutes, but I’m particularly interested in knowing if the samples are abnormally low 5+ consecutive minutes.

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in deciding whether the *underlying process* was abnormally low based on a series of systematic samples taken from the process.  I can't be sure what you mean by "fitted exponential distribution," because the role that phrase plays in your comment is usually played by some kind of criterion, standard, or threshold that has been established by *fiat* or by older data.

Comment: Actually, I think it's in reverse. I have a exponential curve that I know is correct with a known lambda. I want to systematically take samples of new data and compare to the known curve. If the sample show that they're different from the known curve for streak of x minutes, then I know there is a problem. For example, I know that every day my EPX is 6.20 USD. 
 But what happens if for x consecutive minutes I take samples and find that my EPX is 0.02 USD?

Comment: This question is confusing. Earnings per unit sold is exponential what? Maybe show data.

Comment: I added a picture below. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Give me more. What is on $x$-axis? Earnings in Star Trek Credits per year? BTW, to communicate with me you need to add @Carl to the start of the comment.

Comment: @Carl. I normalized the histogram to get P(x) on the y and EPX (Earnings per Unit sold) on the x. EPX is a measure of USD/per units sold every minute... lets assume this EPX stays constant over time. Edit: fixed % -> USD

Comment: More clarification needed concerning units on $x$-axis. What is EPX, is it earnings per minute of total number of units that have been sold, or, is it earnings from sales of units per minute? What is the money coming from? From sales or from sold money making units?

Comment: @Carl EPX is average earnings per minute of total number of units that have been sold. I take the revenue every minute and divide by the sold units.

Comment: (+1) Given now that I finally understand your question. Answer below.

Comment: @fcol first, that distribution isn't all that exponential. The first bar is 6x bigger than the second bar, but the second bar is only about 2x bigger than the third bar. The ratio should be the same.

Comment: Second, if what you care about is when EPX is low for a sustained period, say $n$ minutes, then you could use a summary stat like $n$ point moving average. Compute historical quantiles for this quantity and sound an alarm when the moving average is below a designated quantile or other threshold you choose.

Comment: You could also compute moving order statistics, like the $n$ point moving median or maximum. It all depends on what kind of "low for a sustained period" is relevant to your situation.

Comment: What could cause a drop-off of earnings$-$a general blackout power failure? What you are trying to detect is needed. I will shortly either extend my answer to cover what you want or delete it because some snark downvoted it. I upvoted yours, but cannot upvote my own.